Question on the Necessity of $Q_U Q^\top _U$ in Norm Calculation (from a semidefinite optimization).
I've been reading a paper titled
"S. Bhojanapalli, A. Kyrillidis, and S. Sanghavi, Dropping convexity for faster semi-definite optimization, in Proc. Conf. Learn. Theory, 2016,
pp. 530–582 (https://proceedings.mlr.press/v49/bhojanapalli16.html)" and I've encountered a step in the calculations that I'm struggling to fully grasp.
Specifically, on page 15 (below), during the computation of equation (16), it appears that the paper uses the property $Tr(AB) \le \lVert A \rVert_2 \lVert B \rVert_F$. Here, I am puzzled about the inclusion of $Q_U Q_U^T$ in the norm calculation (here, $Q_U Q_U^T$ represents the projection onto the column space of $U$).

That's my question:
In equation (16), can we not calculate it as
$Tr(\nabla f(X) \nabla f(X) U U^T \nabla f(X) ) \le \lVert \nabla f(X) \rVert_2 \lVert \nabla f(X) U \rVert_F^2$ ?
As an additional question, why is the projection onto the column space of matrix $U$ not simply denoted as $P_U$ but rather written as $Q_U Q_U^T$?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Perhaps to emphasize that it is an orthogonal projection
